# Installing Multiple Apk while Installing One App

Tags: android, installation, apk

I want to Install two apps automatically while installing one App. The apps are separate. Can Anyone help on this.

Comment: Depends on what you exactly mean. What you could easily do is add several activities to the manifest and to the app drawer by adding `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`. Then you'll have 2 app icons to 2 activities, which has the same APK and application.

Comment: Thank you. What I mean is For Example I have three applications Application1, Application2 and Application3 When I Install Application1 Application 2 and 3 should  be installed automatically.

Comment: You could make a simple script using ADB and "install" command to install the generated APKs

Answer (score -1):

This is certainly possible. In your Manifest, declare every `Activity` you want to have 'installed'. Be aware that this means that they all will be deleted too, if one icon will be removed.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

    <uses-permission ... />

    <application
        ...
        >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity1"
            android:label="@string/app_name1"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher1"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity2"
            android:label="@string/app_name2"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher2"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity3"
            android:label="@string/app_name3"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher3"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you. But MainActivity1 MainActivity2 and MainActivity3 need to be in the same package? I have this 3 activities in different applications.

Comment: Yes. Really installing separate APK's is not possible, because this could be misused by hackers as well. Possibly the first app can install the others apps as well, but then the user has to grant this right to the first app and this will stop most users of installing the app in the first place. Why do you want this?

Comment: I have three different apps which is used for three different purposes and have some dependencies also, so to make the user to install all these three at the same time.